# Is it correct to use "now" as an alternative to (present) or (current), such as; my now wife, my now job?

Tags: adjectives

Is it correct to use "now" as an alternative to (present) or (current), such as; my now wife, my now job?

Comment: Welcome to ELU. When you did your research into *now,* did you find it used as an adjective?

Comment: @AndrewLeach Dictionaries site an adjective context, but some of them restrict their examples to a distinctly different definition, though also an adjective: "That style is so now." However I'm inclined to say that the way of using "now" presented in this question is just fine, if only because it falls into the same pattern as a very common adj context for "then", e.g., "I would have chosen a dog, but my then wife preferred cats."

Comment: You can say "my now wife" and "my then wife". But [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=my+now+wife%2Cmy+now+job&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) gives nothing for "my now job".

Comment: When's the last time you heard it, or read it (not in a dictionary)?  *My wife now, my job now, the X now...*  probably outnumber it 10,000 to 1.

Comment: Yes, Weather Vane is right to point out the "certainly used prenominally with the sense 'present', but usually with a more restricted set of nouns than 'present' allows". And TimR is right to point out that even the more likely _now_-noun pairings are rare and getting rarer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth indeed the Ngram shows usage to have been dropping since the late 19th C, although ['my then wife'](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=my+now+wife%2Cmy+then+wife&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) has been on the rise (D-I-V-O-R-C-E?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, in some contexts *now* is used as an adjective just as you suggest, though it’s not all that common in practice. Look in a dictionary and you’ll find [things like this](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/now).